# \multirow in the tabular environment

Tags: tables

How to make vertically centered the text in a multirow in the tabular environment? If I type

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{multirow}

  \begin{document}

  \begin{tabular}{ | p{1cm} |  p{2cm} | p{3cm} |}
  \hline 
  Brand & Model & Description \\
  \hline 
  \multirow{2}{*}{Honda} & CRV & super nice car with four wheels \\
  \cline{2-3}
  & CRW & Car that doesn't even exist \\
  \hline
  \end{tabular}

  \end{document}
```

I get the result below. As you can see, the "Honda" name is not well placed vertically : it is not in the middle of the double row. I think I understand what's happening here: the second and third line of my table had been enlarged vertically to fit the long descriptions in the third columns; but it look likes the command \multirow ignored this fact and still acts as if these rows had their normal size.

What to do to put "Honda" in the center of its box ?

[image]

Comment: I keep my solution, I don't have a better one at the moment. Using `makecell` could perhaps improve the situation.

Answer (score 1):

A solution  consists in entering the `\multirow` command in the last row, with a negative argument. I added some vertical padding to the rows, with the `cellspace` package (hence I had to add a small correction for positioning the contents of the multirow cell):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{3pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{3pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ | p{1.2cm}| p{2cm} | S{p{3cm}}|}
  \hline
  Brand & Model & Description \\
  \hline
                               & CRV & super nice car with four wheels \\
  \cline{2-3}
  \multirow{-2}{*}[2pt]{Honda} & CRW & Car that doesn't even exist \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]